# Why is my player not taking damage from an enemy?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on simple battle system in Unity and I want to make my enemy attack player when he reaches him. After the attack I want the player health to get reduced by damage. The problem is that when my enemy reaches player he doesn't give him any damage despite the fact that console displaying "attacking" information.

Player Script

```
public class MovementController : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public int maxHealth = 20;
    public int currentHealth;

    public HealthBarScript healthBar;
    

    private void Awake()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    }
    
    
    public void PlayerTakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;

        healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
    }

    public void PlayerHeal(int addHealth)
    {

        if(currentHealth < maxHealth)
        {
            currentHealth += addHealth;
        }
        else if(currentHealth > maxHealth)
        {
            currentHealth = maxHealth;
        }
        

        healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
    }   
}
```

Enemy Script

```
public class EnemyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform target;
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float stoppingDistance;

    private float timeBtwAttack;
    public float startTimeBtwAttack;

    public int damage = 1;

    public MovementController _player;

    void Awake()
    {       
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
        timeBtwAttack = startTimeBtwAttack;
    }

    void Update()
    {            
        Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
        transform.rotation = rotation;


        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) > stoppingDistance)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) < stoppingDistance)
        {
            transform.position = this.transform.position;
            Attack();           
        }            
    }
    public void Attack()
    {
        
        if(timeBtwAttack <= 0)
        {
            _player.PlayerTakeDamage(damage);
            Debug.Log("Attacking");                     
            
            timeBtwAttack = startTimeBtwAttack;
        }
        else
        {
            timeBtwAttack -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }   
    
}
```

The game is in 3D

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure that the health is reduced and it is not just the healthbar that is not updating? Another problem could be that the damage value in your enemy script is set to 0 in the inspector.

Comment: I have noticed that if my player is in prefab that doesnt work but if he is unpacked from prefab it works. The thing is he must be in prefab because this enemy is spawning from spawn point in my game, if I put  player out from prefab he can't be attached to the enemy script...

Comment: If you can't set a variable in inspector then you will have to set the variable at runtime. One way to get the player is by setting it's tag to "Player" and then add this into the `start` method of your enemy: `_player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<MovementController>();`

Comment: There is a small logical mistake inside the `playerHeal` routine. Remove the else after the first if and keep the 2nd if. If you are not calling `PlayerHeal` twice in a row, he can have temporary more than max health.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, I think you are just not updating the healthbar in the UI, put this code in attacking and see

```
Debug.Log("Current Health: ", _player.currentHealth);
```

Comment: If the player is taking damage, then the problem is in the healthbar.

Comment: I have noticed that if my player is in prefab that doesnt work but if he is unpacked from prefab it works. The thing is he must be in prefab because this enemy is spawning from spawn point in my game, if I put  player out from prefab he can not be attached to the enemy script...

Comment: If you are spawning the player then use tag to detect it from other scripts. FindWithTag()